# Optimizing geohash query

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

I want to see, if I can use geohash with polygons.

Geohash is normal string, however the SQL query is bit different from what usually is using with geohashes.

The question has nothing to do with geohashes, so I did not tagged it with "geohash".

So:

We have table like this:

```
create table poly(
   ghash    varchar(12) not null primary key,
   place_id int not null
);

insert into poly values("sr", 1);
insert into poly values("sx", 1);
insert into poly values("sxe0h", 1);
insert into poly values("sx7pu", 1);
insert into poly values("sxe0hebm5", 1);
```

now, suppose I search "sxe0heb", i want to return "sx", "sxe0h", "sxe0hebm5", because all these have same prefix with search string ("sx", "sxe0h"), or search string have same prefix ("sxe0hebm5")

The question is not how to do it, but how to do it efficiently.

Best thing I can imagine is:

```
select * from poly where ghash = 'sxe0heb%' union -- collects sxe0heb*
select * from poly where ghash = 'sxe0he' union -- collects subprefix
select * from poly where ghash = 'sxe0h' union
select * from poly where ghash = 'sxe0' union
select * from poly where ghash = 'sxe' union
select * from poly where ghash = 'sx' union
select * from poly where ghash = 's'
```

but since the geohash may be 12 characters, you need union of 12 sql statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it efficiently by doing something like...

```
SET @polystring = "sx";
select * from poly where ghash LIKE CONCAT(@polystring, "%")
  OR ghash IN ( 
    SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 1), SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 2), 
    SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 3), SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 4), 
    SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 5), SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 6), 
    SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 7), SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 8), 
    SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 9), SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 10), 
    SUBSTR(@polystring, 1, 11));
```

Comment: how is this different from what I send? "or" and "in (...)" are basically unions

Comment: It can calculate the values in the IN first, then there's only one query. Your optimiser might convert yours to do something similar to mine, but you'd have to do an EXPLAIN to see. If @polystring is only 2 chars, then there's only 2 values in the IN.

Comment: however, strangely it does not use index

Comment: That will probably depend on the size of the table.

Comment: yes, tried on bigger table and seems it uses. also it does not use temporary table (MySQL 5.6)